# Calculate previous experience in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like (**df**), with millions of rows. It contains information related to sells of different individuals to different countries.

Note: Each row has a different id-prod-d-year:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
               year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2004, 2005, 2004), 
               prod = c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "M", "Z", "Z", "M"), 
               d = c("PER", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "ECU", "ECU", "SPA"), 
               value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10)), 
          class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA,  -10L))
```

I need to create variables by destination (d) that collect relevant information about firms' previous percentages in this destination compared to other destinations in the previous years. Therefore, the new data looks like **df_new**:

```
df_new <- data.frame(df, 
                     exper_lag_ECU=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.44, 0),
                     exper_lag_PER=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     exper_lag_SPA=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     exper_lag_USA=c(0, 0, 0.66, 0.66, 0.9, 0.93, 0.95, 0, 0, 0)
                     )
```

For example, if firm A sells to USA in 2002, I want to know what is the % that this firm sold to USA before (compared to other destinations in the portfolio), e.g. 2000=2+2001=3+2001=4 (over a total value of 1+2+3+4). Therefore, in 2002, I will assign a experience of (9/10 = 0.9) to firm A in the new variable "exper_lag_USA". The same intuition applies for the rest of the variables and observations.

I need an integrated solution without using neither loops, nor divisions (merge) of data, nor manual imputation of different destinations (d), as I have hundreds in my dataset.

Any clue?

Comment: Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305855/is-it-legit-to-delete-and-repost-a-question-that-gets-no-answers).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `tidyverse` like this...

```
library(tidyverse)
df_new <- df %>% 
  left_join({.} %>% #create a dataframe from df to join to the original
              group_by(id, year, d) %>% 
              summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% #consolidate by product
              group_by(id) %>% 
              mutate(cumval = cumsum(lag(value, default = 0))) %>% #total sales
              group_by(id, d) %>% 
              mutate(exper = cumsum(lag(value, default = 0)) / cumval, #total by d
                     exper = ifelse(is.nan(exper), 0, exper)) %>%   #correct 0/0 
              ungroup() %>% 
              select(id, year, d, exper) %>% 
              pivot_wider(names_from = d, names_prefix = "exper_", 
                          values_from = exper, values_fill = 0))

df_new
   id year prod   d value exper_PER exper_USA exper_ECU exper_SPA
1   A 2000    X PER     1         0 0.0000000 0.0000000         0
2   A 2000    Y USA     2         0 0.0000000 0.0000000         0
3   A 2001    X USA     3         0 0.6666667 0.0000000         0
4   A 2001    Y USA     4         0 0.6666667 0.0000000         0
5   A 2002    X USA     5         0 0.9000000 0.0000000         0
6   A 2003    X USA     6         0 0.9333333 0.0000000         0
7   A 2007    M USA     7         0 0.9523810 0.0000000         0
8   B 2004    Z ECU     8         0 0.0000000 0.0000000         0
9   B 2005    Z ECU     9         0 0.0000000 0.4444444         0
10  B 2004    M SPA    10         0 0.0000000 0.0000000         0
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I was struggling a lot to find the solution.